# Nodejs: JSONStream parse method regex

Tags: regex, json, node.js, jsonstream

I have a payload like this

```
{
    "rows": [{
        "id": "1234",
        "data": {
            "updatedby": "uid1",
            "resource": {
                "resourceid": "abcd"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1235",
        "data": {
            "updatedby": "uid2",
            "resource": {
                "resourceid": "pqrs"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1236",
        "data": {
            "updatedby": "uid3",
            "resource": {
                "resourceid": "bert"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

I need to extract the content of the RESOURCE tag only from the json payload. Can you please help me formulate the regex? The below is what I tried and it doesn't invoke the parser.data method.

```
var parser = JSONStream.parse(['rows', true, /^resource/]);

parser.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('received the payload -do something');
});
```

Comment: Why do you need a regex for that? It's a JSON object, you can access the values by using the keys like `obj['rows'][0]['data']['resource']`

Comment: @rednaw: If OP's dataset is big, it won't fit in memory.

Comment: Indeed, I did not got for directly accessing the object as it might fail for memory. with streaming, memory will not be an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a Regex:

```
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('data.json')
.pipe(JSONStream.parse('rows.*.data.resource'))
.on('data', console.log.bind(console))
```

which outputs:

```
{ resourceid: 'abcd' }
{ resourceid: 'pqrs' }
{ resourceid: 'bert' }
```

Comment: Thanks. Im reading from an HTTP Response and streaming it. Not quite sure why it did not work when I tried the same before. It works now !

Comment: Can you help me with these points as well a. When do we have to use Regex, any documentation that explains as to how to build the expression?

Comment: For instance to get back `rows.*.data.resource` and `rows.*.data.result`, you can use a regex for the last item: `JSONStream.parse(['rows', true, 'data', /res(ource|ult)/])`

Comment: Thanks Paul. Unfortunately I dont have enough points to do voteup

Comment: @PaulMougel How can we use a similar filter by value? Say we need to find resourceid= 'abcd'.

Comment: I believe you an use the second argument of `JSONStream.parse(pattern, map)` (see [doc here](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream#jsonstreamparsepattern-map)) to filter out elements: If `map` returns a nullish value, nothing will be emitted.